# how will google treat http://yoursite.com/page?a=1 and http://yoursite.com/page?a=2 will it treat them different?

Tags: url, google

how will google treat yoursite.com/page?a=1 and yoursite.com/page?a=2 will it treat them different or same url.
Or is there any solution i want google to treat same page but with different content. All though the meta tag will be same.

Comment: What does that even mean? "The same page with different content?" Google doesn't care that you've laid the page out in a visually similar configuration...

Answer (score 4):

Google is aware of get parameters so it will treat them as two separate pages. This means that you also need to provide different content do avoid duplicate content penalty.

Despite that they will be treated differently I will advice you to user pretty/seo friendly URLs.

Answer (score 1):

These are different URLs, so Google (and all other search engines that I'm aware of) will treat them as two different URLs. If you're showing the same content on those pages, Google will generally notice that they're identical and only show one of them in the search results. If they're not showing the same content, they'll generally be treated the same as any other independent pages on your site.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you take advantage of parameter handling in Google Webmaster tools. True, it is better to have friendly URLs by the way of a URL Rewriter, but until you're ready to deploy that (there are probably higher priority issues), it's good to make sure that Google knows what your parameters are and has them marked properly.

See my picture from Google Webmaster Tools pasted below.

For example, you might tell it to ignore a parameter that carries a session or user related value (look at Amazon URLs for an example -- non-essential items can be ignored by the spider).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Specify your canonical
see http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/product.php?item=swedish-fish" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Both will be treated differently. How can the same page have different content?

Answer (score 0):

Both will be treated differently as it is a different URL. You will also come across duplicate meta tags if you have exactly the same tags!